# Data modeling attributes and entities

Tags: database-design

I was going through the following data modeling exercise found [here](https://database-modelling.com/exercise/managing-apex-legends-community-tourneys):

> A Twitch streamer can host any number of tournaments for his
> community. Each tournament  consists of a maximum of 20 teams. A team
> in turn consists of a maximum of three players, one  of whom is the
> team leader. Each tournament has any number of rounds. A community
> moderator  manually sets the status of the tournament to started,
> checked and completed. Each team can  achieve a certain number of
> points in a round. These are made up of the placement and the  number
> of kills.

The solution provided in the link is:

[image]

Can anyone explain why tourney_id and team_id are attributes of a participant? Given the requirements I feel like they should be attributes of the 'round' entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why tourney_id and team_id are attributes of a participant? Given the requirements I feel like they should be attributes of the 'round' entity.

`tourney_id` is an attribute of the `round` table already, which makes sense because **every** `round` belongs to a **single** specific `tourney`, making it have a direct relationship.

`team_id` does not make sense on the `round` table because every `team` implicitly partakes in **every** round. This is known because a `team` belongs to a **single** specific `tourney`, and **every** round belongs to a **single** specific `tourney`, so that means for a given `tourney` **all** `teams` that relate to it, indirectly also relate to **all** rounds of that tourney. So there's no need to relate `team` directly to `round` and it wouldn't make sense anyway because there are multiple `teams` that partake in the same `round` of the same `tourney`, so you wouldn't be able to store multiple `team_ids` on a single `round` entity.

The relationship between `participant` and `team` is similar to the relationship between `round` and `tourney` in the sense that **every** `participant` belongs to a **single** `team`. So it makes sense to store the `team_id` in the `participants` table.

The `tourney_id` is a little redundant on the `participants` table, because there's an indirect relationship already between `participants` and `tourney` through the `teams` table. But there's nothing wrong with doing that. It allows someone to directly query for all of the `participants` of a given `tourney` (when they don't care about any information from the `teams`).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation

Comment: @sotn Sure thing, no problem!